# Full example of Firebase auth in a GAE python project?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, pyrebase

Specifically I'm looking to verify a token received from the client using `auth.verify_id_token(..)`. I tried the pyrebase package however ..

```
AttributeError: Auth instance has no attribute 'verify_id_token'
```

The docs seem insufficient. A pointer to a complete example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From `Pyrebase` [github-code](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/2c152ae56f83bc653bf6204a3c9f68fa97b9d64a/pyrebase/pyrebase.py#L103) it looks like the method to verify token is `sign_in_with_custom_token()`. So it should be `auth.sign_in_with_custom_token(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to forego the pyrbase package entirely due to extensive list of libs that must be vendored in. Instead went with `firebase_admin`. Seems simple to verify and retrieve the user info given the auth token:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth

cred = credentials.Certificate("path/to/your/firebaseconfig.json")
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

token = '<token id from client side auth>'
user_info = auth.verify_id_token(token)
```